# JS/Web Audio: How do I jump to loopStart immediately, while playing?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm working with the Web Audio API in javascript.
Part of my current project involves a looper, I need to change the start and end points of the looper dynamically.  Which is working.

But I need the playback position of the audio file to move to the start point when I set it.  I've been googling and reading the spec for days, but I can't seem to find an answer.

I know you can set it with the start() function, but I need to change it while it is already playing.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to initiate an event to launch start() immediately when the loop points change ?

Comment: yeah, I was hoping there was a way to jump to a new point without creating a new AudioBufferSource... but there doesn't seem to be.  It seems like an awful lot of work (not in lines of code, but in theory of what is happening) to just change the current playback location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I think the only way to do this is to create a new `AudioBufferSource` using the same buffer.  Adjust this new `AudioBufferSource` with the same loop points as the original and then call `start()` with the correct start time and offset.

Comment: You are correct.  In all my other audio programming there has been a way to dynamically change the current playback spot.  In the Web Audio API, that doesn't seem to be the case.  You have to re-start a new AudioBufferSource and start it at the new point.  That seems fairly inefficient, though perhaps I'm not getting the whole picture from other languages/libraries.

Comment: Creating (and discarding) an AudioBufferSource is supposed to be very light weight; you can share the underlying AudioBuffer between AudioBufferSource nodes.